# assets path is referring to main app in the installed package after webpack build

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I have a vue js ui component which is built using webpack internally. This reusable ui component library has reference to its images like below:

```
     <img src="./assets/logo.png"/>

     <img src="./assets/edit-icon.svg"/>
```

```
     <img src="./assets/delete-icon.svg"/>
```

And when i build this component as library the dist folder has images at dist -> img. And when i use this
component in the main app with npm install, the component is not able to render the images as the path they are referring to is relative to main app.

```
     <img data-v-ad50538c="" src="http://localhost:8080/js/img/delete-icon.92d078a1.svg">
```

I applied below fix to temporarily fix the issue and it works for svg files but i also have other files png,jpg.. etc

```
    module.exports = {
        chainWebpack: config => {
        const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg')
        svgRule.uses.clear()

        svgRule
            .test(/\.svg$/)
            .use('svg-url-loader') 
            .loader('svg-url-loader')
        }
    };
```

I am not sure how to get this fixed for all files i may have in assets folder. I have a bunch of ui library components and they use lot of assets.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be that you're using relative paths. An easy escape would be to replace the prefixed `.` with `@`. Instead of relative paths. Vue/Webpack should do the rest.

```js
// replace
<img src="./assets/logo.png"/>
//with
<img src="@/assets/logo.png"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work too and the relative path still points to the main app.